# How to get a finger print for a public Key in C?

Tags: c, openssl, public-key

I need to calculate fingerprint for a public key in C. Is there a way to do this in C platform?
I am using openSSL library also. Is there any call in openSSL to get this done?

Comment: fingerprint of AES Key? Why does it require to you? Generally, there is fingerprint of X.509 certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Fingerprints are usually associated with asymmetric encryption keys (e.g, RSA, DSA, ECC) — they are not typically used for symmetric keys, such as AES, and as such there is no standard way of doing this. You can certainly take the hash of an AES key using the algorithm of your choice, though.

Comment: thankyou duskwuff for your reply. I needed it for a public key. I understood it wrong. Even for public key is it like taking a hash of the key?